# WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart is not a known element

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I am starting to learn SharePoint App Development for SharePoint 2013 using Visual Studio 2012.  I'm going through the walk through found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx

I'm having problems when trying to add the WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart element to default.aspx.  Here is the code:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ID="XsltListViewWebPart2" 
runat="server" ListUrl="Lists/TestCustomList" IsIncluded="True" 
NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" Title="TestCustomList" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" 
Default="False" ViewContentTypeId="0x"> 
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

I get the error:

Element 'XsltListViewWebPart' is not a known element.

Here is the register line that is added automatically when you create a new SharePoint App Project in VS2012:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages"  Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add it to web part zone?

Comment: I did (see below).  What you can't see here is in the editor (VS2012) 'XsltListViewWebPart' has a green line under it indicating that VS can't find a definition for it.

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" 
ID="full" Title="loc:full" >
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ID="XsltListViewWebPart2" 
runat="server" ListUrl="Lists/TestCustomList" IsIncluded="True" 
NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" Title="TestCustomList" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" 
Default="False" ViewContentTypeId="0x"> 
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>

Comment: Wait, so you are getting this error only in VS? If you deploy page does it work? This kind of errors could happen in VS.

Comment: I get the error in VS, but it also won't let me deploy (from within VS).  The error I get when I try to deploy is: Element 'XsltListViewWebPart' is not a known element.

Comment: Are you developing on sharepoint server? Also is your XsltListViewWebPart tag located in asp:content tag?

Comment: Yes, I am developing on a sharepoint server.  The tag is located in an asp:content tag.  I can run the app without the XsltListViewWebPart tag (it can contact the server, deploy the app, and run it).